# Send email using Vlookup to match email address

Tags: vba, match, vlookup, offset

I am trying to Vlookup a cell to return a match in a contact list.

When it finds that match it should send an email to the person associated with that location.

```vb
Sub vLookupAnotherWorksheet()
    Dim myLookupValue As String
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    Dim myColumnIndex As Long
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myVLookupResult As Long
    Dim myTableArray As Range
    
    myLookupValue = "H3:H13"
    myFirstColumn = 1
    myLastColumn = 8
    myColumnIndex = 8
    myFirstRow = 3
    myLastRow = 13
    
    With Worksheets("EVC_Contact_List")
        Set myTableArray = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn))
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    myVLookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue, myTableArray, myColumnIndex, False)
    
    If IsError(myVLookupResult) = False Then
        Call Send_Email(myvalue)
    End If
    
End Sub
    
Sub Send_Email(myvalue As Variant)
        
    Dim Email_Subject As String, Email_Send_From  As String, Email_Body As String, i As Integer
    Dim Mail_Object As Object, nameList As String, namelist2 As String, o As Variant
    
    Email_Send_From = ""
        
    If Sheets("EVC_Contact_List").Cells(2, 4).Value <> "" Then
        nameList = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("EVC_Contact_List").Range("D2:D29")))
        namelist2 = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("EVC_Contact_List").Range("F2:F29")))
    End If
  
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = "Unit(s) Excceding Days as Loaner"
        .To = nameList
        .Cc = namelist2
        .display
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
End Sub
```

If location XXXX is found on the contact list and Johnsmith@gmail.com is associated with that location it should send an email only to John Smith.

My code is sending an email to everyone on the contact list.

Comment: hi. whats Call Send_Email(myvalue) ? shouldnt be Call Send_Email(myVLookupResult) ?

Comment: I tried call send email (mylookupresult) and it produces the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
nameList = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("EVC_Contact_List").Range("D2:D29")))
```

Should that not be the Vlookup function?